# Java: Add libraries and txt preference files to project

Tags: java, netbeans, libraries, arduino

I'm using [NetBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) to import a series of libraries from my Arduino IDE. I'm following directions from the following link:

http://silveiraneto.net/2009/03/01/arduino-and-java/

This works provided I use the Arduino-0013 version of the IDE install, more current versions do not compile using this method.

I have found that using the Arudino-0013 set as the working directory is NOT necessary if I manually move the "preferences.txt" and "keywords.txt" and "librxtxSerial.so" files into the lib folder in my Java dist (build) folder, and also move the entire Arduino-0013 "Hardware" folder also into my Java dist (build) folder.

When I do this I can run the Java program from the dist directory on the command line. Using the command:

```
java -jar myProgram.jar
```

rather than having to go into the Arudino-0013 as my working directory and use `-cp` to get my program to work (which I haven't worked out how to do incidentally):

Is there a way to include these .txt files and the Arudino hardware folder with all the files it contains when I build the project with NetBeans? The reason I ask is because it's getting annoying having to do this manually every time I do a new build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Netbeans, if you switch from the Projects tab to the Files tab, you'll see that you have a build.xml file.  This is an Ant build.xml file.  You can configure Ant to automatically copy the files for you whenever your build your project.  You would essentially have something like this:

```
<project ...>
    <target name="-pre-compile">
        <copy file="some/path/preferences.txt" todir="../some/dir"/>
        <copy file="some/path/keywords.txt" todir="../some/dir"/>
        <copy file="some/path/librxtxSerial.so" todir="../some/dir"/>
    </target>
    <target name="-post-compile">
        <copy todir="build/dir">
            <fileset dir="some/path/Arduino-0013"/>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

There is more information in the build.xml file about what you can and can't hook into.  The Ant documentation is good, and the Tasks section of the [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) will be particularly useful.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is *not specific to netbeans* but you can try:

Make an [Apache ANT](http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) build file to build your project. In that file make a copy task which will copy txt files in your build. By doing this you will not have to so it manually. See here: http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetbeansedAnt to know how to work with ANT in NetBeans.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a dependencies section in NetBeans for your project. You can then add external libraries to your project, such as local JAR files you've got. The best way would probably be to jar up the text files and Arduino directory together, then add that JAR file as a compile-time (and/or run-time) dependency to your project. Now, when you compile your project in NetBeans it should include the specified JAR file on the classpath and voila.

Sorry to not give you more NetBeans-specific direction, I've only used the IDE a couple of times, but all IDEs will allow you to add local JAR files and third-party libraries as dependencies to your project, you just need to find where in the IDE you can do that.

Another idea that might work is to set NetBeans to use your local copy of Java for compilation instead of the one that came bundled with the IDE, that way you don't need to fuss with project dependencies. Again, I don't know where in NetBeans to set this, but start in the General Settings (or perhaps the Project-specific Settings) and find the Java/compilation section; hopefully there's an option to specify which JDK to use, then point it at your local copy.